# hive 3.1 metastore error on startup connecting to mysql rds

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Trying to startup Hive Metastore 3.1 version connecting to a new MySQL RDS and getting this error. When using Hive 2.3.2 it worked fine (on a separate MySQL RDS instance). Does anyone know what is causing this? Have already initiliased the mysql before starting HiveMetastore process with:

- echo "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS metastore;" > hive_metastore.sql
  echo "USE metastore;" >> hive_metastore.sql echo "SOURCE
  $HIVE_HOME/scripts/metastore/upgrade/mysql/hive-schema-3.1.0.mysql.sql;"

  > > hive_metastore.sql echo "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'hive'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$hive_pasw';" >> hive_metastore.sql echo "REVOKE ALL
  > >     PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'hive'@'%';" >> hive_metastore.sql echo
  > >     "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON metastore.* TO 'hive'@'%';" >>
  > >     hive_metastore.sql echo "CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'ro_hive'@'%'
  > >     IDENTIFIED BY '$ro_hive_pasw';" >> hive_metastore.sql echo "REVOKE
  > >     ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM 'ro_hive'@'%';" >>
  > >     hive_metastore.sql echo "GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW, PROCESS,
  > >     REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'ro_hive'@'%';" >> hive_metastore.sql
  > >     echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" >> hive_metastore.sql echo "quit" >>
  > >     hive_metastore.sql

  18/08/24 00:17:48 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
  18/08/24 00:17:48 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is MYSQL
  18/08/24 00:17:48 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
  18/08/24 00:17:49 WARN DataNucleus.MetaData: Metadata has jdbc-type of null yet this is not valid. Ignored
  18/08/24 00:17:53 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Failed to get database hive.default, returning NoSuchObjectException
  18/08/24 00:17:53 WARN metastore.HiveMetaStore: Retrying creating default database after error: Exception thrown flushing changes to datastore
  javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Exception thrown flushing changes to datastore
          at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:543)
          at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOTransaction.commit(JDOTransaction.java:171)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.commitTransaction(ObjectStore.java:765)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createDatabase(ObjectStore.java:953)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:97)
          at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:751)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:769)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:538)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8661)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8656)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8926)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8843)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
          at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
          at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
  NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
  java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Unknown column 'CATALOG_NAME' in 'field list'
          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createBatchUpdateException(SQLError.java:1163)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1778)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1262)
          at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:970)
          at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:125)
          at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
          at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement.executeBatch(ParamLoggingPreparedStatement.java:366)
          at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController.processConnectionStatement(SQLController.java:676)
          at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController.processStatementsForConnection(SQLController.java:644)
          at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.SQLController$1.transactionFlushed(SQLController.java:731)
          at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractManagedConnection.transactionFlushed(AbstractManagedConnection.java:89)
          at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$2.transactionFlushed(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:450)
          at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.flush(TransactionImpl.java:210)
          at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:274)
          at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOTransaction.commit(JDOTransaction.java:107)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.commitTransaction(ObjectStore.java:765)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.createDatabase(ObjectStore.java:953)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:97)
          at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.createDatabase(Unknown Source)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB_core(HiveMetaStore.java:751)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:769)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:538)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8661)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8656)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8926)
          at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8843)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
          at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
          at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-19740 
After setting hive.metastore.event.db.notification.api.auth to false on hive-site.xml. Hive can start and function normally.